# how to disable autosuggestion of keyboard in android .in phonegap >?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

can you please tell me how to disable autosuggestion of keyboard in android .in phonegap >?

I have input field when i type it.Keyboard  is showing autosuggestion .how to disable it.?

```
<input name="password" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" autocorrect="off" maxlength="240" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input name="password" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h">

    var text = document.getElementById("text-12");

    text.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        e.keyup();
        e.focus();

    }, true);
```